# Can you use aspnet identity token authentication in MVC without web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, identity

My Scenario:

I have an MVC application that currently uses cookie based authentication. 
I have a separate application that is web API but this is purely for rendering media services - I really dont want to move authentication code over here.

What do I want?

Cookies are only sent cross-domain for GET requests - I need more functionality so I have started looking into token based authentication. Every example I find seems to need a web api service with the login. Is there a way to merely generate a token during COOKIE authentication and use this for requests to my media service?

Thanks